# Async with watch function

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

The watch function below filters prop.students. The function alphaLinks passes the value of the prop.students. How do I make it so the function awaits and passes the filtered value. As it is now it passes the value before it's filtered.

I'm using composition API

```
watch( [search, serviceDate, currentGrade, currentHr, mealType], ([searchValue, serviceDateValue, currentGradeValue, currentHrValue, mealTypeValue])  => {
    Inertia.get('/pos', {search: searchValue, serviceDate: serviceDateValue, grade: currentGradeValue, hr: currentHrValue, mealType: mealTypeValue}, {
        preserveState: true,
    })
     alphaLinks(props.students);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inertia [manual visits](https://inertiajs.com/manual-visits) offer event handlers. You can call your function after the request using the `onSuccess` or `onFinish` event handlers. The difference is that the first will run only if the request is successful, while the second runs either if the request is successful or not.

```js
Inertia.get('/pos', { ...data }, {
   preserveState: true,
   onSuccess: (page) => {
      alphaLinks(props.students);
   },
   // or ...
   onFinish: (visit) => {
      alphaLinks(props.students);
   },
})
```

Comment: this makes a lot of sense. Thank you!!